# VBA Running when Excel closed

Tags: vba, excel

I have a challenge, for me at least, I cannot deal with apparently. Can somebody help me or advise on how to make the macro run when Excel is closed?

How can I make the macro run when the Excel is closed via VBA?

```
Sub Upload0()
    ' Upload Webpage content
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "Upload0"

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://cetatenie.just.ro/ordine/articol-11", Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "CetatenieOrdine"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = True
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 1
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

' Deletes empty cells
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

' Adjust column width and delet useless rows
Rows("1:31").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("B28").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Rows("17:309").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Many Thanks to all!

Comment: 1. Are you talking about the workSHEET or the workBOOK? Does the macro has to do with the worksheet in question? 2. I think you should try and formatting the code manually as the {}code brackets do not make it more readable.

Comment: Where are you planning to make this macro run from in case the workbook is closed. VBScript? VB.Net? Something Else?

Comment: Appologizes, you are right: for the WORKBOOK when it is closed: workbook name is Book1.xls

Comment: I am trying it in VBA

Comment: Where does this code exist? In the Book1.xls workbook? Or in another workbook?

Comment: Yes, in Book1.xls workbook in Module 3

Comment: From where do you want to trigger this code? orm another Excel workbook? From another application?

Comment: From this Book1.xls and only this one, because if I work in another exel file it tries to run the macro for that file, which leads to an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Define a boolean flag in a module `Public blnClosedVBA as Boolean` and set it to true in your VBA routine before closing the workbook. Then in your Workbook_BeforeClose event handler (under ThisWorkbook), do this:

```
If blnClosedVBA = True Then 
Cancel = True 'Stops the workbook from closing
'Rest of your code here
blnClosedVBA = False ' Set so next time you try to close the workbook, it actually closes
'Workbook.Close or ThisWorkbook.Close - depends on your answer to my question below
```

That will run the routine only if you have triggered the close event yourself. At the end of the routine, setting the flag to False and triggering another `Workbook.Close` will close the workbook

2: Which workbook should it work for? Should it be 'ThisWorkbook' (the one from which you're running the code), 'ActiveWorkbook' (the one activated), or another one?

Comment: Hi Matt and thank you so far! I need for the Book1.xls only, because i wrote my macro in Module it doesn't work when I move it to ThisWorkbook.

Comment: Yes you should leave your current code in the Module, then in ThisWorkbook, you will need to amend the BeforeClose event. In there, you can call your Upload0 sub - replace the `'Rest of your code here` line in my answer with `Upload0`.

Comment: To confirm, you want to run your code when the workbook is closed VIA VBA (i.e. using ThisWorkbook.Close). You don't want the code to run when the workbook is closed already...?

Comment: No, I need it to work both: opened and closed workbook. However, the issue is that if the workbook is opened, then  the code tries to run macro for the one at which I am looking or working, i.e. active, but I need it to do the job only for 1 specific file Book1.xls for instance.

Comment: You won't be able to run this in a closed workbook (unless you open it first). If you want the query table to appear in a specific workbook, change the first line of your add statement to this: `With Workbooks("Book1.xls").Sheets("Sheetname").QueryTables.Add(...` and change the Destination to `Workbooks("Book1.xls").Sheets("Sheetname").Range("A1")`

Comment: Matt, pelase last help, I added some additional functions to the code and I do have problem when I try to work in a different excel file again; I cannot see here how to adjust the code so that it could do it peacefully in the file while I am working in a different one.

Comment: You have to specify which book and in which worksheet you want the code to affect - use `Workbooks("XXX").Sheets("XXX").Range("XXX")` whenever you want to do something. E.g. for your Delete Empty Columns bit in your post above, do `Workbooks("XXX").Sheets("XXX").Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp`. Fill in the XXX with the correct names - this will ensure that the columns are deleted from the correct sheet

Answer (score 1):

> 1.How can I make the macro run when the workbook is closed via VBA?

Short answer: you can't do that. Your code is part of the workbook and it can't run unless the workbook is loaded in Excel. You might be able to move the code to a separate add-in workbook that you elect to load by default (using "Excel Options|Add-Ins") when Excel starts. But Excel would still need to be running somewhere on your computer.

You could write a completely separate program that does what you want, writing the results of the web query into an Excel workbook. I'm assuming here that you want the workbook to always contain up-to-date data when it's referenced by yourself (when Excel is running of course) or some other resource. If you can acquire a copy of Visual Basic 6 (it may not be possible to achieve this legally) then that's mostly syntactically the same as VBA. Next closest would be VB.Net. This is going to be technically somewhat complex.

> 2.Also, I have issue making this macro working ONLY for one workbook but not active ones:

This one we *can* deal with: this line:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
```

means that the following code will always run against the worksheet that has the focus (i.e. is "active" - the sheet that would receive keyboard input if you typed something). That's what `ActiveSheet` does. Try replacing `` `ActiveSheet with something like ``ThisWorkbook.Sheet1`, where`Sheet1` is the name for the sheet that you see in the "Properties" window in the VBA editor where it says "(Name)".

Comment: Hey Mike, there is still a problem, for instance if I have another excel opened or I am working with a different file, then the Macro runs for that file in which I am working and if i doesn't have sheet name properly mentioned, than it chokes...